# perl regex - pattern matching

Tags: perl

Can anyone explain what is being done below?

```
 $name=~m,common/([^/]+)/run.*/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$,;
```

Comment: Testing to see if a string matches a regular expression but not doing anything with the result.

Comment: The code checks variable `$name` for a match against `common/*/run*/*/*`, in term of __shell__ (bash, zsh, csh, ...), perhaps match against to some path in filesystem. It can be rewritten as `$name =~ m!common/.*?/run.*?/.*?/.*?$!;`

Comment: Re "*`common/*/run*/*/*`  in term of shell"*, I think that's what it was meant to do, but that's not what it does. `.*` can match strings containing `/`. /// @PolarBear Re "*It can be rewritten as*", All those `?` are pointless. Your rewrite can match `common/foo/run/bar/baz/moo/moo/moo/moo/moo/moo/moo/moo/moo`. I don't think you intended that. Remember that `^/.*?/$` matches `///`.

Comment: @ikegami Indeed I did not intended it, if I would use something of this kind in the code I would perhaps chosen other approach. One line of code does not say much about intentions of the programmer or the problem -- it is not clear what perl script supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `common`, `run` and `/` are match themselves.
- `()` captures.
- `[^/]+` matches 1 or more characters that aren't `/`.
- `.*` matches 0 or more characters that aren't Line Feeds.<sup>[1]</sup>
- `$` is equivalent to (`\n?\z`).<sup>[2]</sup>
- `\n` optionally matches a Line Feed.
- `\z` matches the end of the string.

I think it's trying to match a path of one or both of the following forms:

- `.../common/XXX/runYYY/XXX/XXX`
- `common/XXX/runYYY/XXX/XXX`

Where

- `XXX` is a sequence of at least one character that doesn't contain `/`.
- `YYY` is a sequence of any number of characters (incl zero) that doesn't contain `/`.

It matches more than that, however.

- It matches `uncommon/XXX/runYYY/XXX/XXX`
- It matches `common/XXX/runYYY/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX`

The parts in bold are captured (available to the caller).

---

1. When the `s` flag isn't used.
2. When the `m` flag isn't used.